# Most efficient way to execute several threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, performance, threadpool

### You may skip this part:

I am creating an application where the client needs to find the server on the same network.

**The server:**

public static void StartListening(Int32 port)
 {

```
 TcpListener server = new TcpListener(IP.GetCurrentIP(), port);
 server.Start();

 Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
   {
     while (true)
       {
         // wait for connection
         TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
         if (stopListening)
           {                        
             break;
           }
       }
   }));
 t.IsBackground = true;
 t.Start();
```

}

Let's say the server is listening on port 12345

**then the client:**

- get the current ip address of the client  let's say it is 192.168.5.88
- create a list of all posible ip addresses. The server ip address will probably be related to the client's ip if they are on the same local network therefore I construct the list as:

  ```
     192.168.5.0
     192.168.5.1
     192.168.5.2
     192.168.5.3
     .....etc
     .....
     192.168.0.88
     192.168.1.88
     192.168.2.88
     192.168.3.88
     ...etc
     192.0.5.88 
     192.1.5.88
     192.2.5.88
     192.3.5.88
     192.4.5.88
     ..... etc
     0.168.5.88
     1.168.5.88
     2.168.5.88
     3.168.5.88
     4.168.5.88
     .... etc
  ```

Then I try to connect with every possible ip and port 12345. If one connection is successful then that means that I found the address of the server.

---

### Now my question is:

Now I have done this in two ways. I know just the basics about threads and I don't know if this is dangerous but it works really fast.

```
        // first way
        foreach (var ip in ListOfIps)
        {               
            new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
            {
                TryConnect(ip);
            })).Start();
        }
```

the second way I belive it is more safe but it takes much more time:

```
        // second way
        foreach (var ip in ListOfIps)
        {               
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(TryConnect), ip);
        }
```

I have to call the TryConnect method about 1000 times and each time it takes about 2 seconds (I set the connection timeout to 2 seconds). What will be the most efficient and secure way of calling it 1000 times?

---

### EDIT 2

Here are the results using different techniques:

> **1)**  Using threadpool

```
        ..
        ..
        var now = DateTime.Now;
        foreach (var item in allIps)
        {
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(DoWork), item);
        }

        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(PrintTimeDifference), now);
    }

    static void PrintTimeDifference(object startTime)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("------------------Done!----------------------");
        var s = (DateTime)startTime;
        Console.WriteLine((DateTime.Now-s).Seconds);
    }
```

[image]

**It took 37 seconds to complete**

> **2)**  Using threads:

```
        ..
        ..
        var now = DateTime.Now;
        foreach (var item in allIps)
        {
            new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
            {
                DoWork(item);

            })).Start();

        }

        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(PrintTimeDifference), now);
```

[image]

**It took 12 seconds to complete**

> **3)** Using tasks:

```
        ..
        ..
        var now = DateTime.Now;
        foreach (var item in allIps)
        {

            var t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>

                DoWork(item)
            );                                
        }

        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(PrintTimeDifference), now);
    }

    static void PrintTimeDifference(object startTime)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("------------------Done!----------------------");
        var s = (DateTime)startTime;
        Console.WriteLine((DateTime.Now-s).Seconds);
    }
```

[image]

**It took 8 seconds!!**

Comment: Why do you think the ThreadPool "takes much more time" ? Did you actually try?

Comment: Yeah it takes about 20% more time. Dont know why...

Comment: You should implement a simple client/server discovery protocol using multicast UDP rather than constructing the IP list like you are planning on doing.

Comment: I mean trying out all this 1000 ips takes about 20 seconds. The ip is found within the first 5 seconds usualy because most likely the servers ip will contain the same firs 3 bytes (192.168.1.x) but you are right I will try with UDP instead

Comment: UDP alert - there is more than one subnet, so routers are involved. UDP broadcast will not work by default and UDP multicast requires that the server ask for service, the router to support it and is anyway not appropriate for network discovery.

Comment: I don't know if the Tasks/Threads run in the same order as you defined it. If it doesn't have to be the same order, your time calculation has an error, because it's not sure that the time calculation is done when all other threads finished. To ensure that all other threads finished you have to wait for them:

For threads you can use `thread.Join();`. For Tasks there is `Task.WaitAll(tasks)`. For ThreadPool-Threads it's a bit more complicate, but here is an example with `ManualResetEvent`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3dasc8as(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: I also make sure that my output was corret by placing a breakpoint. the ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem( will execute untill other threads are done executing. In all the threads I output stuff to the console and the last comment that is written is the one where it prints the time. Lastly I also know when it finishes because I see the console stop when all the tasks are done...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case I would prefer the solution with the ThreadPool-Threads, because creating 1000 Threads is a heavy operation (when you think of the memory each thread gets).
But since .NET 4 there is another solution with the class `Task`.
Tasks are workloads which can be executed in parallel. You can define and run them like this:

```
var t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoAction());
```

You don't have to care about the number of threads used because the runtime environment handles that. So if you have the possibility to split your workload into smaller packages which can be executed in parallel I would use Tasks to do the work.

Comment: What do tou mean by execute in parallel. I get confused... to me parallel and multythreading seem to be the same thing. What is the difference between executing a method in a thread pool than in a Task?  Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: I just tried to say that you can only use this solution if the tasks don't interfere (they are independent from each other). In your case they do not interfere with each other so I would strongly suggest the use of Tasks.

Comment: 'In this case I would prefer the solution with the ThreadPool-Threads' - this solution takes 'much more time'. Why would anyone want the poor-performing design?  This is just strange.  'You must use the design with the bad performance because the design with the good performance is bad'.  Can anyone explain?

Comment: The best solution is not always the best solution.
Maybe using Threads is faster, but way more memory-wasting.
ThreadPool-Threads are handled by the runtime environment, and I guess it knows more about performance tuning and memory optimization than any of us.

Comment: Never in the history of software development have so many promoted a poorly-performing solution to so few:)  The RTE makes a guess at optimization - it doesn't get it right of all requirements.  In this case, it seems like the best soution is indeed the best solution - the OP tested them and the other solutions were worse.

Comment: Jasd take a look at my edit number 2. There is not so much difference on memory. Maybe cause all of them fill the memory. There is a big difference on cpu usage. I wish I had another computer right now to test it on a different one.

Answer (score 2):

Both methods run the risk of creating way too many Threads.

A thread is expensive in the time it takes to be created and in memory consumption.

It does look like your 2nd approach, using the ThreadPool, should work better. Because of the long timeout (2 sec) it will still create many threads, but far less then 1000.

The better approach (requires Fx 4) would be to use `Parallel.ForEach(...)`. But that too may require some tuning.

And a really good solution would use a broadcast (UDP) protocol to discover services.

Comment: There is more than one subnet and UDP broadcast is blocked by most routers by default - UDP broadcast will not work.

Answer (score 2):

Now I made my own benchmark.

Here is the code:

```
class Program {
    private static long parallelIterations = 100;
    private static long taskIterations = 100000000;

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        Console.WriteLine("Parallel Iterations: {0:n0}", parallelIterations);
        Console.WriteLine("Task Iterations: {0:n0}", taskIterations);
        Analyse("Simple Threads", ExecuteWorkWithSimpleThreads);
        Analyse("ThreadPool Threads", ExecuteWorkWithThreadPoolThreads);
        Analyse("Tasks", ExecuteWorkWithTasks);
        Analyse("Parallel For", ExecuteWorkWithParallelFor);
        Analyse("Async Delegates", ExecuteWorkWithAsyncDelegates);
    }

    private static void Analyse(string name, Action action) {
        Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
        watch.Start();

        action();

        watch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1} seconds", name.PadRight(20), watch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
    }

    private static void ExecuteWorkWithSimpleThreads() {
        Thread[] threads = new Thread[parallelIterations];
        for (long i = 0; i < parallelIterations; i++) {
            threads[i] = new Thread(DoWork);
            threads[i].Start();
        }
        for (long i = 0; i < parallelIterations; i++) {
            threads[i].Join();
        }
    }

    private static void ExecuteWorkWithThreadPoolThreads() {
        object locker = new object();
        EventWaitHandle waitHandle = new ManualResetEvent(false);

        int finished = 0;
        for (long i = 0; i < parallelIterations; i++) {
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((threadContext) => {
                DoWork();
                lock (locker) {
                    finished++;
                    if (finished == parallelIterations)
                        waitHandle.Set();
                }
            });
        }
        waitHandle.WaitOne();
    }

    private static void ExecuteWorkWithTasks() {
        Task[] tasks = new Task[parallelIterations];
        for (long i = 0; i < parallelIterations; i++) {
            tasks[i] = Task.Factory.StartNew(DoWork);
        }
        Task.WaitAll(tasks);
    }

    private static void ExecuteWorkWithParallelFor() {
        Parallel.For(0, parallelIterations, (n) => DoWork());
    }

    private static void ExecuteWorkWithAsyncDelegates() {
        Action[] actions = new Action[parallelIterations];
        IAsyncResult[] results = new IAsyncResult[parallelIterations];

        for (long i = 0; i < parallelIterations; i++) {
            actions[i] = DoWork;
            results[i] = actions[i].BeginInvoke((result) => { }, null);
        }
        for (long i = 0; i < parallelIterations; i++) {
            results[i].AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();
            results[i].AsyncWaitHandle.Close();
        }
    }

    private static void DoWork() {
        //Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(taskDuration));
        for (long i = 0; i < taskIterations; i++ ) { }
    }
}
```

Here is the result with different settings:

Parallel Iterations: 100.000
Task Iterations: 100
Simple Threads      : 13,4589412 seconds
ThreadPool Threads  : 0,0682997 seconds
Tasks               : 0,1327014 seconds
Parallel For        : 0,0066053 seconds
Async Delegates     : 2,3844015 seconds

Parallel Iterations: 100
Task Iterations: 100.000.000
Simple Threads      : 5,6415113 seconds
ThreadPool Threads  : 5,5798242 seconds
Tasks               : 5,6261562 seconds
Parallel For        : 5,8721274 seconds
Async Delegates     : 5,6041608 seconds

As you can see simple threads are not efficient when there are too much of them.
But when using some of them they are very efficient because there is little overhead (e.g. synchronization).

Comment: I am puzzled by your analysis of the results. Simple Threads, in the better case, took essentially the same time as all the alternatives. In the worst case, it was much slower. Therefore, what you have demonstrated is that if you carefully tune your usage of threads, you can manually match the performance of these built-in mechanisms [but not beat them by any significant amount], but if you err in your tuning, you can be much, much worse. Therefore, you have shown one should *not* attempt to "roll your own". Thank you for all the timings - good to see actual numbers.

Comment: Hmm. Your results for Parallel For don't seem consistent relative to the other alternatives. Might be worth testing *combinations* of Parallel For with each of the threading choices. Done correctly, the combination might be superior. For example, it would be interesting if Simple Threads + Parallel For beat the alternatives under some circumstances. That would show that "roll your own" *can* sometimes be superior. [I don't have enough experience with this topic to construct the ideal combination, or to know whether it makes any sense to attempt that...]

Answer (score 1):

Well there are pros and cons to this approach:

1. Using an individual thread per connection will (in theory) let you make all connections in parallel, since this is a blocking I/O operation all threads will be suspended until the respective connection succeeds. However, creating 1000 threads is a bit of an overkill on the system.
2. Using the thread pool gives you the benefit of reusing threads, but only a limited number of connection tasks can be active at one time. For example if the thread pool has 4 threads, then 4 connections will be attempted, then another 4 and so on. This is light on resource but may take too long because, as you said, a single connection needs about 2 seconds.

So I would advise a trade-off: create a thread-pool with about 50 threads (using the `SetMaxThreads` method) and queue all the connections. That way, it will be lighter on resources than 1000 threads, and still process connections reasonably fast.

Comment: The ThreadPool will start to grow with 2 Threads/second. And while changing the Min/Max threads of the TP is not recommended, this case would benefit from a lower Maximum.

Comment: @Henk Holterman: Yes, you're right. I usually cap it manually to the number of cores before using it.

Comment: OK, why is it overkill if it works and leads to the best performance?  It's only done once and the threads die off, releasing all those 'heavy resources' that .NET seems to need for threads.

Comment: @Martin James: AFAIK the default stack size for a single thread is 1MB, so starting 1000 threads will use quite a bit of memory. Ok it gets released soon, but I don't think you can assume that every system will have 1GB of free memory for thread stacks. Not to mention the initial 1000 context switches when each thread is suspended until the connection succeeds.

Comment: That 1GB of memory can be paged out.  I don't know if the default stack size can be tweaked on .NET?  1000 context-switches is not an important factor.  Some sort of async connect mechansim seems like a good approach?